# Spread object literal function argument and return shorthand

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a shorter way to write this? (Spread object literal argument and return all its properties):

```
 export const selectUser = ({ fullName, email, userType }) => ({
    fullName,
    email,
    userType,
  }),
);
```

Comment: This looks very much like an identity function. What do you need it for?

Comment: @Bergi It looks like a ngrx-store selector. You use copies to avoid accidental modifications of the state. A common library for this is immer.js

Comment: @jabaa I mean, yes, it looks like a (shallow) `copyUser` function, but the OP hasn't even stated that purpose.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right. I was too deeply focused on my current context and made some assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (from *"return all its properties"*) the object has exactly these 3 properties, you can:

```
export const selectUser = obj => ({ ...obj });
```

Comment: @lance-p Do you really need a shallow copy? Otherwise you could use `export const selectUser = obj => obj;`